# Proof of solutions to set of equations

Tags: number-theory

I am confused on how to rigorously prove the solutions to this set of equations:
$$
x^y= z, y^z= x, z^x = y
$$
With that set of equations, the question states, prove that $x=y=z=1$ for x,y,z all in the positive reals?

What is the full solution to this problem?

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but irst and third equation together yield $$x^{z^x}=z$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are not all equal to $1$, then they either they are all greater than $1$ or are all less than $1$. In either case we have $x<z<y<x$—contradiction.

Comment: How did you get that they all have to be greater or less than 1? Can you expand on that briefly?

Comment: For instance, if $z>1$, then $x^y>1$, so $x>1$.